# Error:discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: set_image() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: discord, discord.py

My code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 934486335408984064:
        try:
            global selfie
            selfie = message.attachments[0].url
            print(selfie)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command(aliases = ['love'])
async def loveS(ctx, name: str, age: int, *, about_me = None):
    like = 0
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Рейтинг {like}❤️", description =f"Меня зовут {name}\nМне {age}** лет\n**{about_me}**", colour=0x2f3136)
    embed.set_image(selfie)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

я хочу чтоб моя команда !love отправляла фотку и текст отправляющего эмбедом, вот пример: !love Mark 18 Hello World и дальше его фотография, я пробовал много методов и единственный способ который я нашел это создать команду ивент которая будет копировать ссылку фотографии и отправлять в функцию loveS в строку с `embed.set_image(selfie)` но мне выдает ошибку, что 2 аргумента стоят типа, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Будьте добры перевести вопрос на русский язык

Comment: я хочу чтоб моя команда !love отправляла фотку и текст отправляющего эмбедом, вот пример: !love Mark 18 Hello World и дальше его фотография, я пробовал много методов и единственный способ который я нашел это создать команду ивент которая будет копировать ссылку фотографии и отправлять в функцию loveS в строку с `embed.set_image(selfie)` но мне выдает ошибку, что 2 аргумента стоят типа, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

я решил эту проблему я забыл указать url = selfie